# PHP client for solr cloud 5.3

Tags: php, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm trying to connect to a SolrCloud instance from zookeeper through a PHP client, I can't find any.
In solrj, things are much easier, I just provide the zookeeper hosts and ports and that's it.

```
<?php

  $options = array
  (
    'hostname' => 'host',
    'port'     => myPort,
    'path'     => 'solr/offers',
  );

  $client = new SolrClient($options);
  $query = new SolrDisMaxQuery();
  $query->addParam("title","blue jeans");
  $query_response = $client->query($query);

  $response = $query_response->getResponse();
?>
```

this was my code for connecting to a single solr instance using pecl/solr client

In java, I did something like this:

```
List zkhosts = new ArrayList();
zkhosts.add(0, "localhost:2183");
CloudSolrClient server = new CloudSolrClient(zkhosts,"/solr");
SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();
server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
parameters.set("qt", "/select");
parameters.set("q", "blue jeans");

parameters.set("collection", "offers");
QueryResponse response = server.query(parameters);
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```

I need to do the same thing in PHP, any help?

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to use Solr 5.3 and use SolrCloud with Zookeeper, and also use the PECL library for solr...?

Comment: SO, I came up with a simple solution and it's been on production for months now, and its working perfectly.
I used a redis key to store all the live Solr instances as a string, for example: "host1:8983,host2:8983,host3:8983" and i randomly distributed the calls to the hosts in the redis key.

Of course, I wrote a php console command to read the live nodes from zookeeper and put them in the redis key. I update it every 5 minutes because my solr cloud is very stable.
I hope this helps you @Dan